# The encoded url from MS Teams planner not working as expected

Tags: microsoft-planner, microsoft-graph-plannertasks

I have an API that sends tasks to MS `Tasks by Planner and To Do` with attachments.

**Sample API body:**

```
payload = { 
  ...
    
  "title": "I am sending task from python Notebook",    
  "Notes": "Add some useful notes here",    
  "attachments": [
        {
          "url": "https://example.com/test/1123?tenantId=1223-xxxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx-12234",
           "alias": "attachment"
        }
  ]
}
```

**To be noted:**

On the backend side, I am encoding the URL and then passing, otherwise, it won’t accept the request and throws the error - Inspired from MS Docs [plannerExternalReferences resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/plannerexternalreferences?view=graph-rest-1.0#example)

Now the task goes into the planner and the attachment URL looks like this - which is expected.

```
https://example.com/test/1123%3FtenantId%3D223-xxxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx-12234
```

[image]

when the user clicks the link on the planner, the browser is not able to read the `parameters` from the URL.

what could I do to resolve the issue? or that something MS has to do on their side.

Comment: Hi, Are you facing the same issue if you are opening the planner task in browser by clicking the web icon.

Comment: @Prithvi-MSFT, The behaviour is same when I open the `Planner` in the browser from the  icon and then I try to open the attachment.

Comment: @Prithvi-MSFT, are there any updates done by MS on the issue?

Comment: Hi @Gaurav Gupta, This issue seem to be related to planner app instead of teams platform. Since you have already added tags for planner app, hopefully someone from planner team will reach out to you.